# When should we split the data into train, valid and test datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, exploratory-data-analysis

In EDA we actually get insights about the data. That is completely fine but what i cannot understand is on which dataset should we do the EDA?

Should we do the EDA on train dataset or train + valid dataset or on the complete dataset.

I have seen many other questions similar to this and they have controversial answers.
[Question1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/424263/should-exploratory-data-analysis-include-validation-set?newreg=267a80c9506b46a8a54e149a9858fab7)
[Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653458/validation-dataset-and-test-dataset/63653665#63653665)
[Should exploratory data analysis include validation set?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/424263/should-exploratory-data-analysis-include-validation-set)

More precisely can anyone given an better explanation why i should/shouldn't use the validation dataset in the EDA than the above questions?.

Comment: Both answer complement each other: You should do feature selection etc. on a train set, but for the very first actions of visualizing your data, getting summary statistics, etc you should look at the whole dataset.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please don't keep re-posting the same question. If there's an aspect to yours that you don't think is addressed in the one indicated as a duplicate, then edit yours to focus on that.