# How to justify the usage of "Radial Basis Function" as a kernel for SVM

Tags: svm, kernel-trick, libsvm

I ran SVM with several kernels on my data. RBS has the best performing results. The task is similar to the text classification. I wonder how I can explain why RBS is actually the best kernel for my task. I can simplify the task a bit, and compare RBS with only linear. I user libsvm to train and test.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, since it is recommended NOT to use the RBF kernel for text classificiation, see for example [here](http://www.svm-tutorial.com/2014/10/svm-linear-kernel-good-text-classification/).

When you compared the models, did you use cross validation using train, test and validation set? See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set) why this is needed. If you need to choose the `best' model, you need an additional test set, and to optimize the parameter for the RBF kernel and the parameter C, you need the validation set ;).