# Lowess optimal selection of bandwidth

Tags: nonlinear-regression, exploratory-data-analysis

I'm currently running lowess on a dataset, and am wondering what bandwidth I should use. What are some guidelines for selecting the bandwidth? Or is it largely arbitrary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to other machine learning problem for hyperparameter tuning. We can use a test data set or validation data set to select the "best one" in a separate data set.

Difference between testing and validation data set can be found here 
[What is the difference between test set and validation set?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set)