# cross validation for model evaluation

Tags: cross-validation

I want to use cross validation to validate the results of my model,
However, I'm confused how to use it.

Should I split my data to 3 sets (Train, Validation,test) and validate the results on test set?

or make the validation on the whole data set?

or use validation as a training phase and test on the test set?

It is good to mention that my dataset is almost 500 records.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should divide your dataset in three sets(train, validate and test).

As you are having 500 records, a good division may be [250, 125, 125]. Where you are having 250 records for training, 125 validating and 125 testing.

You may find [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set) useful.

Comment: even though I dont want to tune parameter? , I only want to validate the model I'm getting after testing?

Comment: As per my understanding, Validation is itself used for tuning hyper-parameters. You've written, you don't want to tune those parameters. Then why to use validation. Correct me if I'm wrong. I also want to know what you mean by "I only want to validate the model I'm getting after testing".