# What is the difference between validation and cross validation?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, dataset

I hear the dataset is divided into three parts

1-training

2-validation

3-test

in the 2- validation
Do you mean cross validation or what difference does it make?

Comment: Many answers on this site already https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set/96869#96869