# What is the difference between a validation and a development set?

Tags: machine-learning, validation

For most of the ML problems we have train,test and validation sets in a dataset as discussed in this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set). I have a dataset where I have train, development and evaluation sets. train and evaluation sets are obviously train and test sets. What about development set? Is it the same remaining validation set or it has a different concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is the validation set. Related [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_sets#/Validation_dataset) entry:

> A validation dataset is a dataset of examples used to tune the hyperparameters (i.e. the architecture) of a classifier. It is sometimes also called the development set or the "dev set"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the timely help!

Comment: @DevLoverUmar you're welcome. I think you've accepted and then rejected the answer. Is that by mistake?