# Does CNN need to have training data and validation data?

Tags: conv-neural-network

I am using a simple CNN model, and I want to run a test, input is an image of Bird, the output is either "0" or "1", where "1" means the output is correct, is a bird.

Do I need to set my training data and validation image data?
If yes, can I weigh it as 90% training data and 10% validation data?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not dependent on CNN's, but rather what you wish to do with the model. If you want a model that interpolates the data you have already, then having only training data is fine. But if you want to make predictions of future (possibly independent) data, you will want to validate your model.

Comment: @Galen. Thanks. Is there a difference between "validation data" and "test data"?

Comment: @Galen Thanks. Is there a difference between "validation data" and "test data"?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set

Comment: @galen, Thank you