# How to interpret result for MultiModelByRegression in RapidMiner?

Tags: regression, classification, logistic, rapidminer

I couldn't find any information in the [documentation](http://rapid-i.com/content/view/36/209/) of rapidminer. I have a data set with the following attributes:
`a,b,c,d,e`.
The types are: `numerical`, `binomial`, `binomial`, `binomial`, `binomial`.
Binomial values are given as `{true, false}`.

The last one is the label I want to be able to predict. So the value to predict is a true/false decision. I understand that I have to use logistic regression for that.

My module chain looks like this.

```
Read CSV -> Set Role -> Nominal To Binary -> Classification by Regression
```

`Set Role`: I can only set one attribute as the predictor attribute. How can I set all other input attributes as predictor attribute too?

`Nominal to Binary`: The binomial values are given as Strings "true" and "false". That's why I do the conversion here.

The output for [MultiModelByRegression](http://rapid-i.com/api/rapidminer-4.6/com/rapidminer/operator/learner/meta/MultiModelByRegression.html) is:

```
MultiModelByRegression (prediction model for label is_helpful)

      16.889 * b ^ 1.000
    + 9.553 * c ^ 2.000
    + 0.102 * a ^ 1.000
    - 71.438
      76.078 * b ^ 4.000
    + 38.618 * c ^ 1.000
    + 0.082 * a ^ 1.000
    - 88.701
```

The `Performance Vector Output` is:

```
    true false  true true   class precision
pred. false 2706    129 95.45%
pred. true  636 40  5.92%
class recall    80.97%  23.67%
```

I know how to interpret the above.

All of this is done with the training set, which is already labelled
with the correct classes. How do I apply the test set at this point?
I suppose I need the test set to somehow evaluate the results of my classifier, right?
Anyway, I am really confused here and I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: question: You say "I know how to interpret the above." but the title of the question states otherwise. What is correct here ? Up to this point I answered only the questions appearing in the body.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding "Set Role"**

"prediction" is referring to the predicted label AFTER the application of a model to an exampleset. By default, all attributes with role "regular" are used as predictors. So the operator `Set Role` can be skipped here.

**Regarding application of a model**
You have to load the test-set separately and apply the model to it. Something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.2.000">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.2.000" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true" height="443" width="636">
      <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="5.2.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="load_train" width="90" x="45" y="30">
        <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Samples/data/Golf"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="naive_bayes" compatibility="5.2.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="Naive Bayes" width="90" x="179" y="30"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="5.2.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="load_test" width="90" x="45" y="210">
        <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Samples/data/Golf-Testset"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="apply_model" compatibility="5.2.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="Apply Model" width="90" x="313" y="120">
        <list key="application_parameters"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="performance_binominal_classification" compatibility="5.2.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="Performance" width="90" x="447" y="120"/>
      <connect from_op="load_train" from_port="output" to_op="Naive Bayes" to_port="training set"/>
      <connect from_op="Naive Bayes" from_port="model" to_op="Apply Model" to_port="model"/>
      <connect from_op="load_test" from_port="output" to_op="Apply Model" to_port="unlabelled data"/>
      <connect from_op="Apply Model" from_port="labelled data" to_op="Performance" to_port="labelled data"/>
      <connect from_op="Performance" from_port="performance" to_port="result 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Performance" from_port="example set" to_port="result 2"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 3" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Simply copy and paste the code to the XML tab in the design-perspective to make it work.

However, in order to make a solid statement about the accuracy of your classifier you should perform a xvalidation. See e.g. the process under /Samples/03_Validation/XValidation_Nominal

Additionally, in order to reduce the confusion about the two types of model-applications, i.e. XValidation on the first dataset and application of the final model on the second /holdout-set, I recommend this question:
[Why only three partitions? (training, validation, test)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9357/why-only-three-partitions-training-validation-test)

Comment: Hi steffen! Thank you for your answer. Sorry for the ambiguity. I meant that I know how to interpret the performance vector output. But I dont know how to interpret the output from multimodel by regression..

Comment: I tried your approach and adjust it a little bit, but I constantly get the error "input example set does not have a predicted attribute." Could you take a look at the code to see what might be the issue? I'd really appreciate that...
How can I add a larger part of xml in here? I wasnt able to do so... :(

Comment: @funkywon 1. I suggest to edit your question, not to add an answer 2. Just copy the xml code into the editor, select it and click on the code - symbol ({}). If this does not, what is the actual error ? Where does the "xml-insertion" fail ?

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt work, I have to insert 4 whitespaces before every line :((..the xml seems to be fine, the problems section doesnt show that there is anything wrong. the error appears when I try to run.. Could I email you the xml text so that you could take a look at it? long text insertion on stackexchange doesnt seem to do it...

Comment: @funkywon hm strange, but you can send me the file. I added my email-address to my profile.