# Is cross validation needed?

Tags: logistic, cross-validation

Suppose we have training data set and a test data set. The outcome variable is binary. Is it usually necessary to split the training data set so that there is a cross validation data set? Or can you use the whole training data set to build a model and the use this model on the test data set? For logistic regression, for example, would cross validation really help? If so, what type would be best?

Comment: There are plenty of **great answers** on this site that try to answer your question. Please see [Training with the full dataset after cross-validation?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/training-with-the-full-dataset-after-cross-validation), [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72324/2798) and [many](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79905/cross-validation-including-training-validation-and-testing-why-do-we-need-thr?rq=1) of the [other](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65128/nested-cross-validation-for-model-selection) threads on this topic.

Comment: One more: [Internal vs external cross-validation and model selection](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64147/internal-vs-external-cross-validation-and-model-selection)

Answer (score 5):

`Cross validation` has two purposes :

- when you don't use cross validation and randomly select a part of data as train and other part as test, you may have a high accuracy in that part for train and test but when you select another train and test data you may have lower accuracy. Cross validation methods like `n-fold cross validation` or etc. will help to find best fit model based on your database. with lowest error on all parts of data.
- In some cases cross validation will help to find some parameters of model like `C` in logistic regression that you can find some documentation about it in `MATLAB` help center or in `R` documentation files.

So as we discoursed `cross validation` has a critical rule to find a reliable model for your database. You should select best cross-validation technique based on your model structure and your sample size. `5-fold cross validation` is a well known technique. You can increase the `k` in k-fold cross validation If you have more sample size.

Answer (score 0):

In general cross validation is always needed when you need to determine the optimal parameters of the model, for logistic regression this would be the $C$ parameter.

As a first start you can look into k-fold validation, if you are using R look at (http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/training.html) 
or 
python (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation)

Comment: The goal of CV is **not** to estimate parameters but to estimate the **generalization performance** and **stability** of your **full learning procedure**. If you choose to determine parameters with CV (you probably mean with a grid search), you **should** add another layer of cross validation, to cross-validate the grid search process itself. In other words, the full learning procedure, regardless of whether you are estimating parameters or hyper-parameters, should be cross validated. Please see the links I provided in the comments to the OP.

Comment: Am I right that in principle two CVs have to be performed? The first time to get the model and then again to find the best parameters?